# Getting the index or the value of a single object inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

i'm doing a MERN app

What happens is that, i'm trying to pass only one value, or index of an object in an onClick function so i can make some changes in the backend, but, it passes the whole objects not only one that i need, so, how can i get only one element from an array of objects?

This is my data, and this is the array of objects

[image]

And this is my code and how i'm trying to catch only one single value or index, in the onClick function specifically the dispatch(checkTasks(_id, todo))

```
 <TodoContainer>
            {todo.map(data => {
              const { homework, _id, createdAt } = data;
              return (
                <HomeworkContainer key={_id}>
                  <HomeworkHeader>
                    <HomeworkHeaderName>
                      {user?.result?.name} <br />
                      <span>{moment(createdAt).fromNow()}</span>
                    </HomeworkHeaderName>
                    <span
                      style={{ padding: "0rem 2rem" }}
                      onClick={() => dispatch(deleteTasks(_id))}
                    >
                      <HomeworkButtonDelete />
                    </span>
                  </HomeworkHeader>
                  <AllTodoStuff white>
                    <SpanTodoStuff>
                      Date : {moment(createdAt).format("DD-MM-YY")}
                    </SpanTodoStuff>
                  </AllTodoStuff>

                  {homework.map((rightTodo, i) => {
                    const { todo, complete } = rightTodo;

                    return (
                      <>
                        {complete === false ? (
                          <AllTodoStuff key={i} Uncompleted>
                            <SpanTodoStuff>{todo}</SpanTodoStuff>

                            <p>
                              <span style={{ padding: "0rem 2rem" }}>
                                <IconDone
                                  onClick={() =>
                                    dispatch(checkTasks(_id, todo))
                                  }
                                />
                                {console.log(i)}
                              </span>
                              <span style={{ padding: "0rem 2rem" }}>
                                <IconCancel />
                              </span>
                            </p>
                          </AllTodoStuff>
                        ) : (
                          <AllTodoStuff key={i} white>
                            <SpanTodoStuff>{todo}</SpanTodoStuff>

                            <p>
                              <span style={{ padding: "0rem 2rem" }}>
                                <IconDone />
                              </span>
                              <span style={{ padding: "0rem 2rem" }}>
                                <IconCancel
                                  onClick={() =>
                                    dispatch(checkTasks(_id, todo))
                                  }
                                  />
                                                                  {console.log(i)}

                              </span>
                            </p>
                          </AllTodoStuff>
                        )}
                      </>
                    );
                  })}
                </HomeworkContainer>
```

And the output of the function it's both index, in this case

```
0
1
```

But i only need, the 0, if i catch the 0 or the 1 in the other case, but, if i grab both, both are going to change, and only have to change one, the one i click

Comment: Right now, you don't have your log statement inside the onClick handler, but in the JSX. Everything inside there will be executed on component render. Please try again when putting the log statement into the `onClick` function?

Furthermore, it is considered code smell to compare boolean values against their literals (true/false). Consider updating your ternary operator to something like: `!compete ? <component_a> : <component_b>`

Comment: `onClick={() => dispatch(checkTasks(_id, rightTodo))}` if you want to pass the entire element object at each index. I also totally agree with @MauriceA. on the boolean comparison, but will take it a step further when using the false evaluation to take the truthy ternary path, you should reverse the cases, i.e. `complete ? <component_b /> : <component_a />`.

Comment: Thank you Maurice A, and Drew Reese for taking the time to help me out, thank you for the advice of my complete ternary, i'll change it !

And about passing getting specific object or index of my array of objects, it worked perfectly, thank you so much !